# RDLC Report Merge 2 Rows In 1 Row NAV 2013

Tags: dynamic, rdlc, nav

I have a question about RDLC Report in NAV 2013

I have 2 rows like this

**Store10     2.00     5.00     0.00    0.00**

**Store10     0.00     0.00     3.00    9.00**

And I want 1 row by merging these, like;

**Store10     2.00     5.00     3.00    9.00**

How can it possible ?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,

If rows first column is unique for your data. You should Group On this field in Visual Studio .

I couldn't add an image for reputation..

After that, Your line will shown merged. So, values maybe missing.

For calculating values effectively, You must use SUM(Field) syntax in "Table Cell Expression"

Like That

=SUM(Fields!RecNo.Value)